# django1.8- global name "" is not defined in the "def get_queryset" query

Tags: python, django

I got an error of "global name region is not defined" in the line of "queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region)".

The mistake might because I shouldn't validate if the queryset result has corresponding record in Database  in "def clean".

So I tried to remove "def clean" and put this validation in def get_queryset (the 2nd views.py). Then if I enter something with no queryset result in dababase, it doesn't report error on the form page.

Could any help to find how could I change the code? Thanks in advance.

**views.py**

```
class ResultView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    model = Result

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        region = form.cleaned_data['region']     
        country= form.cleaned_data['country']     

        if not Result.objects.filter(region=region,country=country).exists():
            self.add_error(ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))
        return cleaned_data

    def get_queryset(self):
        form = InputForm(self.request.GET)
        queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region)   -//here wrong

        return queryset
        return Result.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))
```

**views.py  - if removing def clean-- the error function doesn't work**

```
class ResultView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    model = Result

    def get_queryset(self):
        form = InputForm(self.request.GET)        
        if form.is_valid():
            country = form.cleaned_data['country']
            region = form.cleaned_data['region']

        if country !="" and region !="":
                if Result.objects.filter(region=region,country=country).exists():
                    try:
                        queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region,country=country)
                    except:
                        self.add_error(ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))
            return queryset
        return Result.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))
```

**HTML Snippets**

```html
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {% csrf_token %}
      {{ formset.management_form }}
      {{ formset.errors }}
      {{ formset.non_field_errors }}
      {{ formset.non_form_errors }}
      {{ form.non_field_errors }}
     ......    

        <!--region-->   --it allows to select none
        <div class="field {% if field.errors %} field_error{% endif %}" >
            <label> Select Region:
            {{ form.region }}
                {% for region in form.region.choices %}                    
                     <option value="region" name= "region" id="id_region">{{region}} </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </label>
        </div>
```

I don't add " {{ form.non_field_errors }} " because some of the fields it allows to be blank

**traceback**

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\list.py" in get
  159.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\XXX\result\views.py" in get_queryset
  61.             Result.objects.filter(region=region,country=country).exists()
```

Comment: Have you imported Result?

Comment: @Gocht, yeah, it is imported for sure. from result.forms import InputForm;
from result.models import Resultt,Input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is obvious:

```
    form = InputForm(self.request.GET)
    queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region)
```

in this scope, the `region` is not defined, of course.

you need to retrieve the region from the form, sanitize it and then do the query with it

```
    form = InputForm(self.request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=form.cleaned_data['region'])
```

and further down, it should be:

```
 def get_queryset(self):
    form = InputForm(self.request.GET)        
    if form.is_valid():
        country = form.cleaned_data['country']
        region = form.cleaned_data['region']

        if country !="" and region !="": # <--- moved one intend to right
            if Result.objects.filter(region=region,country=country).exists():
                try:
                    queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region,country=country)
                except:
                    self.add_error(ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))
            return queryset
        return Result.objects.all()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it still reports the same error, I uploaded the traceback in the post for your reference.

Comment: @Elena same mistake in `if supply_chain !="" and region !="":` you need to move this whole if block one intend to right. otherwise `region` is not defined

Comment: sorry it is a typo on the post, it should be if country !="" and region !=""; but I need this validation condition to check if there is corrsponding queryset result in database. Please correct me if I misunderstood what you meant, thanks.

Comment: do you think if I could keep a separate "def clean"? Maybe this way the code is cleaner like the 1st views.py in the post?

Comment: @Elena you have to clean the form in your get_queryset method. your code this way is also clean, dont worry about cleanness right now, worry about functionality ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94885/discussion-between-elena-and-doniyor).